# Expressive and composable error types

Tags: haskell, error-handling, composition

I am struggling with the best way to report errors in a set of functions that should compose nicely, in a library I'm working on.

Concretely, I have functions that look like:

```
foo, bar, baz :: a -> Maybe a
```

where `foo` can fail in only one way (a good fit for `Maybe`), but `bar` and `baz` can fail in two different ways each (good fits for `Either BarErrors` and `Either BazErrors`).

One solution is to create:

```
data AllTheErrors = TheFooError
                  | BarOutOfBeer
                  | BarBurnedDown
                  | ...
```

and make all the functions return `Either AllTheErrors`, which expresses the range of errors that might be raised by a *composed sequence* of these functions at the expense of expressing the range of errors possible for each *individual* function.

Is there a way I can get both? Maybe with something other than monadic composition? Or with type families (waves hands)...?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

The [Control.Monad.Exception](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/control-monad-exception) library allows strongly typed exceptions to be used in non IO code. This allows functions to throw errors, and easily compose with functions that throw different errors. For example:

```
{-# LANGUAGE RankNTypes, MultiParamTypeClasses, FunctionalDependencies #-}
{-# LANGUAGE FlexibleInstances #-}
import Prelude hiding (catch)
import Control.Monad.Exception


data FooException = FooException deriving (Show, Typeable)
instance Exception FooException

data BarErrors = BarErrors deriving (Show, Typeable)
instance Exception BarErrors

data BazErrors = BazErrors deriving (Show, Typeable)
instance Exception BazErrors

-- sample functions    
foo :: (Throws FooException l) => a -> EM l a
foo a = return a


bar :: (Throws BarErrors l) => a -> EM l a
bar _ = throw BarErrors

baz :: (Throws BazErrors l) => a -> EM l a
baz a = return a


-- using all at once:

allAtOnce :: (Throws FooException l, Throws BarErrors l, Throws BazErrors l) =>
             a -> EM l String
allAtOnce x = do
  _ <- foo x
  _ <- bar x
  _ <- baz x
  return "success!"

-- now running the code, catching the exceptions:

run :: a -> String
run x = runEM $ allAtOnce x `catch` (\(_ :: FooException) -> return "foo failed")
        `catch` (\BarErrors -> return "bar failed")
        `catch` (\BazErrors -> return "baz failed")


-- run 3 results in "bar failed"
```

See also the papers [Explicitly Typed Exceptions for Haskell](http://users.dsic.upv.es/~jiborra/papers/explicitexceptions.pdf) and [An Extensible Dynamically-Typed Hierarchy of Exceptions](http://community.haskell.org/~simonmar/papers/ext-exceptions.pdf) for more details on using this library.

Comment: After doing some research, what I think will suit my library is to define my library's functions polymorphically in the `Failure` class from the 'failure' package, here: http://hackage.haskell.org/package/failure . That lets me express the kinds of exceptions that can be raised in the type sig, and gives my users the option of using something simple like `Maybe`, or something more robust like control-monad-exception (which provides an instance). Thanks again.