# How can I compose error types in Haskell?

Tags: haskell, exception, error-handling

Is there an agree-on best practice for aggregating and handling typed errors across many layers of functions in a larger Haskell application?

From introductory texts and the [Haskell Wiki](https://wiki.haskell.org/Handling_errors_in_Haskell), I take that pure functions should be total - that is, evaluate to errors as part of their co-domain. Runtime exceptions cannot be completely avoided, but should be confined to IO and asynchronous computations.

How do I structure error handling in pure, synchronous functions? The standard advice is to use `Either` as return type, and then define an algebraic data type (ADT) for the errors a function might result in. For example:

```
data OrderError
    = NoLineItems
    | DeliveryInPast
    | DeliveryMethodUnavailable

mkOrder :: OrderDate -> Customer -> [lineIntem] -> DeliveryInfo -> Either OrderError Order
```

However, once I try to compose multiple error-producing functions together, each with their own error type, how do I compose the error types? I would like to aggregate all errors up to the UI layer of the application, where the errors are interpreted, potentially mapped to locale-specific error messages, and then presented to the user in a uniform way. Of course, this error presentation should not interfere with the functions in the domain ring of the application, which should be pure business logic.

I don't want to define an uber-type - one large ADT that contains all possible errors in the application; because that would mean (a) that all domain-level code would need to depend on this type, which destroys all modularity, and (b) this would create error types that are too large for any given function.

Alternatively, I could define a new error type in each combining function, and then map the individual errors to the combined error type: Say `funA` comes with error-ADT `ErrorA`, and `funB` with `ErrorB`. If `funC`, with error type `ErrorC`, applies both `funA` and `funB`, `funC` needs to map all error-cases from `ErrorA` and `ErrorB` to new cases that are all part of `ErrorC`. This seems to be a lot of boilerplate.

A third option could be that `funC` wraps the errors from `funA` and `funB`:

```
data ErrorC
    = SomeErrorOfFunC
    | ErrorsFromFunB ErrorB
    | ErrorsFromFunA ErrorA
```

In this way, mapping gets easier, but the error handling in the UI-ring needs to know about the exact nesting of functions in the inner rings of the application. If I refactor the domain ring, I do need to touch the error unwrapping function in the UI.

I did find a similar [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8320855/expressive-and-composable-error-types), but the answer using [Control.Monad.Exception](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/control-monad-exception) seems to suggest runtime exceptions rather than error return types. A detailed treatment of the problem seems to be [this one](https://www.parsonsmatt.org/2018/11/03/trouble_with_typed_errors.html) by Matt Parson. Yet, the solution involves several GHC extensions, type-level programming and lenses, which is quite a lot of stuff to digest for a newbie like me, who simply wants to write a decent application with proper "by the book" error handling using Haskell's expressive type system.

I heard that PureScript's extensible record would allow to combine error enums more easily. But in Haskell? Is there a straightforward best practice? If so, where can I find some documentation or tutorial on how to do it?

Comment: Why not invert?  Use a single error type which has already done the locale conversion. Forget the ADTs. Your design will have to have a large table of all errors somewhere anyway.  You lose the ability to "catch" arbitrary specific exceptions Java-style, but I think that's good. I find there is a difference between "something went wrong" errors and "normal operation" errors, and you can give the latter a more privileged representation, so that there is type pressure to handle them.

Comment: My key concern is that the domain code should not need to depend on types declared in some outside layer, because this would break the Clean Code dependency rule. The problem is not a large table of errors somewhere, but the declaration of a single error type that all code then needs to import as dependency.

Comment: After some reading, it seems to me that the extensible exceptions mechanism that are by now standard in GHC (see the [original paper](https://simonmar.github.io/bib/papers/ext-exceptions.pdf)) should also work for subtyping errors.

Answer (score 1):

For your aggregatable `Error` Type, I suggest that you look up [validation: A data-type like Either but with an accumulating Applicative](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/validation).

The library is exactly one module, consisting of only a handful of definitions. The `Validation` type within the package is **essentially** (though not literally):

```
type Validation e a = Either (NonEmpty e) a
```

What's worth pointing out is that accumulation of errors is achieved using the applicative combinators, namely `liftA2`, `liftA3` and `zip`. You **cannot** accumulate errors inside a `monad` comprehension, aka `do` notation:

```
user :: Int -> Validation DomainError User
userId :: User -> Int
post :: Int -> Validation DomainError Post

userAndPost = do 
  u <- user 1
  p <- post . userId $ u
  return $ (u,p)
```

The applicative version on the other hand, may yield two errors:

```
userAndPostA2 = liftA2 (,) (user 1) (post 1)
```

The monad version of the `userAndPost` function above can never produce two errors for both `user` and `post` not being found. It's always one or the other. Applicatives, while theoretically recognized as being less powerful than monads, have unique advantages in some practices. Another edge that an applicative has over a monad is that of concurrency. Taking the examples above once again, one can easily deduce why monads inside a comprehension can **never** be executed concurrently (Notice how fetching of the post depends on the user id from the fetched user, thus dictating that execution of one action depends on the result of the other).

As for your concern for breaking code modularity when opting to define a single disjointed union type `DomainError` for all domain level errors, I'd venture to say there is no better way to model it, provided that the said domain-specific error type is only constructed and passed around by functions in the domain layer. Once say the HTTP layer calls the function from the domain layer it would then need to translate the error from the domain layer to that of its own, e.g via a mapping function similar to:

```
eDomainToHTTP :: DomainError -> HTTPError
eDomainToHTTP InvalidCredentials = Forbidden403
eDomainToHTTP UserNotFound = NotFound404
eDomainToHTTP PostNotFound = NotFound404
```

With one such function, you can easily transform any `input -> Validation DomainError output` to `input -> Validation HTTPError output`, thus preserving encapsulation and modularity within your codebase.

Comment: Thanks for pointing out the validation library! It does solve the problem on how to combine multiple errors. As far as I understand it, though - and what you point out - the individual errors must still be of the same type. I do consider this to be a big problem, it forces my inner business logic to depend on a type from an outer ring of my program's architecture, which violates the dependency rule of the Clean Code/Onoin Architecture. I'm foremost looking for a way to solve this dependency problem.

Comment: @UlrichSchuster I understand the `DomainError` that shayan mentions to be a sum type defined in the Domain Model (i.e. the 'innermost ring'). How does that break the dependency rule?

Comment: I think there are two separate issues: (a) errors from the domain model (innermost ring) somehow need to be combined with errors from other rings, like use-case errors or UI errors. How to do that? (b) even if there is one large domain error type, this type would be too large for most functions, because they only might return one or two elements of that type each. This issues is described [here](https://www.parsonsmatt.org/2018/11/03/trouble_with_typed_errors.html).

Comment: @UlrichSchuster Your referred article argued against an ```AllPossibleErrors``` type used throughout the entire application. An uber-type for all errors shouldn't be considered for a layered architecture in the first place. Also, error cases becoming broader in the outer layers shouldn't necessarily be the case. Notice how my example ```eDomainToHTTP``` function takes in 3 possible inputs and returns 2 possible outputs. In other words, the error cases shrank as a result of transition from one layer to the other.